# common lisp error ...*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (< J N) should be a lambda expression

Tags: lambda, common-lisp

```
*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (< J N) should be a lambda expression
```

This is the code where it's happening:

```
(defun SORTALIST (x) (setq i 0) (setq j (+ i 1))
   (cond ((< i n)) (cond ((< j n))
   (cond ((> (car (nth (i) (x)))(car (nth (j) (x)))))
   (EXCHANGE (nth (i)(x))(nth (j)(x)))
   (setq j (+ j 1)) (SORTALIST (x)))
   (t (setq j (+ j 1)) (SORTALIST (x))))
   (t (setq i (+ i 1)) (setq j (+ i 1)) (SORTALIST (x)))) (x))
```

I changing things around for an hour, I can't figure out where I could be fix.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to find anything that's not wrong with your code:

- You can't use local variables to pass values between recursive calls. `i` and `j` need to be function parameters instead. (Also, `setq` is not the right way to introduce new local variables. Use `let` for that.)
- Don't stuff multiple statements into a single line, and use different indentation widths to mark the nested conditions. It's no wonder you can't identify the problem with such atrocious formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I will change every things you told.